# requireNativeComponent Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/PermissionsAndroid'

Tags: node.js, react-native, error-handling, node-modules, react-native-web

I am using react native and trying to use the

```
react-native-qrcode-scanner
```

(I also npm installed: react-native-camera and react-native-permissions)

The command I did to install all of the above packages is: npm install module@latest --save

package to read QR codes but when I try to run my code this error pops up :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js:9:24
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/PermissionsAndroid'
   7 |   NativeModules,
   8 |   ViewPropTypes,
>  9 |   requireNativeComponent,
     |                        ^
  10 |   View,
  11 |   ActivityIndicator,
  12 |   Text,

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-qrcode-scanner/index.js:4:35
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/PermissionsAndroid'
  2 |
  3 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
> 4 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    |                                   ^
  5 |
  6 | import {
  7 |   StyleSheet,

web compiled with 2 errors and 3 warnings
```

(I didn't include the warnings because I don't think they are needed to solve the problems if you do need them tell me I will update this)

So my code was pulled from a random link on Google I don't really remember which but here is the code

```
  import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

  const MyQRCodeScanner = () => {
    const onSuccess = (e) => {
      console.log(e.data);
      // e.data contains the QR code data
    };
  
    return (
      <QRCodeScanner onRead={onSuccess} />
    );
  };
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1537#issuecomment-601167089

Comment: I actually found out that the react-native-qrcode-scanner is now archived on github. Is there another library that does something similar.

Comment: I guess archive is not our issue

Comment: So I tried their answer to the problem and it doesn't work for me do you have another idea to try and fix this

Comment: hey @ArnaudGirard did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no but I didn't use it in the end